# Understanding kernel patch submitting check list? related to testing patch?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What does this mean by following checklist rule

**Tested after it has been merged into the -mm patchset to make sure
    that it still works with all of the other queued patches and various
    changes in the VM, VFS, and other subsystems.**

mm patchset means memory management related patches ?

Please correct my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upon a time, the -mm patchset indeed contained memory management related patches for future verions of the kernel.

That checklist entry is outdated; you should test against the [linux-next tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/linux-next.html).